# what does allowLossyConversion mean in ios

Tags: nsstring

I am using the `dataUsingEncoding(encoding: NSStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: Bool = default) -> NSData?` function to convert String to NSData, but I don't get what `allowLossyConversion` actually means.

Is it similar to Lossy compression? Can anybody help me understand this?

Comment: `If flag is YES and the receiver can’t be converted without losing some information, some characters may be removed or altered in conversion. For example, in converting a character from NSUnicodeStringEncoding to NSASCIIStringEncoding, the character ‘Á’ becomes ‘A’, losing the accent.`(from the doc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If flag is YES and the receiver can’t be converted without losing some information, some characters may be removed or altered in conversion. For example, in converting a character from NSUnicodeStringEncoding to NSASCIIStringEncoding, the character ‘Á’ becomes ‘A’, losing the accent.

Answer (score 0):

This option allows you to get `data` even if the text uses characters that cannot be converted correctly.
This can be useful when working with arbitrary text and generating a QR code from it.

For example, the company name `McDonald's` has an apostrophe symbol that cannot be correctly converted into a `data` using `.ascii`.

If in the function you pass `false`:

```
text.data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)
```

you will receive from `"Apple"` -> `"Apple"`, and from `"McDonald's"` -> `nil`.

At the same time, if you pass the `true`:

```
text.data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: true)
```

you will receive from `"Apple"` -> `"Apple"`, and from `"McDonald's"` -> `"McDonald?s"`.